# Laravel - Pass variable to controller from kernel schedule

Tags: laravel

Using laravel schedule command in Kernel.php can you pass a variable to the controller?

Kernel.php

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\TestController@fetchInvoices(20)')->everyMinute();
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\TestController@fetchInvoices(100)')->everyFiveMinutes();
```

TestController.php

```
public function fetchInvoices($id){
      dd($id);
}
```

My goal is to have 2 crons run at different times without having to duplicate the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no Laravel expert but I don't think using a Controller is the right method here.

Try and build the fetchInvoices method into an Artisan command with options.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#writing-commands

Artisan commands can easily be scheduled.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands

Comment: It's indeed best-practice to only use controllers for requests coming from website users. Cronjobs should be calling a commandline interface such as artisan. It could very well be that a controller and an artisan command share implementation, in that case create a separate class for that implementation, which can be called from both the controller and the artisan command.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the downvote. I guess it wasn't the reply the OP wanted (although still seems a valid point to me) I would have posted this as a comment but didn't have enough rep points.

Answer (score 1):

the `Schedule::call()` function looks like it can accept parameters:

```php
/**
 * Add a new callback event to the schedule.
 *
 * @param  string|callable  $callback
 * @param  array  $parameters
 * @return \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent
 */
public function call($callback, array $parameters = [])
{
    $this->events[] = $event = new CallbackEvent(
        $this->eventMutex, $callback, $parameters
    );

    return $event;
}
```

so try:

```php
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\TestController@fetchInvoices', array('10'))->everyMinute();
```

Comment: That did it thanks. I should have looked under the hood on the function to see if it accepted other variables.

Comment: I have been using this since I asked the question. Seems to be broken in Laravel 8, still looking for a solution without having to create an artisan command

Comment: @ChadPriddle did you find the solutions? im also interested on it

Comment: @Mcfaith I ended up using commands in the scheduler. It is a bit more involved but it works great. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 8 has a little change in the implementation, you will need to pass the name of the variable in an array as defined in the method you are calling. Below code should work for you.

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\TestController@fetchInvoices', ['id' => 10])->everyMinute();
```

$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\TestController@fetchInvoices', ['id' => 10])->everyFiveMinutes();